# Can I stop doing mini-games in Pokemon Dream World?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Is there any reason to keep doing mini-games on Pokémon Dream World after you get over 10000 points. (Beside the games vs the pokemon you want to capture)?

When you are in [Pokémon Dream World](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dream_World), you get [points](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dream_World#Dream_Points) specially when you do mini-games (20pts each). This is the best way to getter points (at moment 06-03-2011). But after 10000 points you have all Pokémon from Pokemén Dream World ready to be capture, so you need only hope to find one while in the [Island of Dreams](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dream_World#Island_of_Dreams), beside that, do I need keeping doing the mini-games, or can I stop ? There is some kind of punishment, or you only find old pokémon (not the new one, already available) or any sort of prejudice ??

Comment: Actually, the way we tag questions here, that's an excellent analogy. If you have a question about jQuery, the way tags are applied here, there's no need to tag it with JavaScript; of course a question about jQuery relates to JavaScript. In this case, of course a question about pokemon-fifth-gen is a Pokémon question. See [this question on meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2585/8366): questions about a game should use a single tag for that game.

Comment: Good point @DaveDuPlantis ^_^ Thank you for the link, really helpful =) +1 for the "excellent analogy" hehehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one has answered: There is no punishment for not playing the games. However, now there is a reason to collect more than 10,000 points: You can obtain more rows in your garden as you obtain more Dream Points. You can get up to ten rows, but I think you'd need 100,000 points.

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dream_World)

Comment: There's also the possibility that they'll add new rewards in future.